# Changed Event when Background Dependency Property of Custom control changes

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I'm creating custom WPF controls with specific properties (and events).
My Button should be able to change its Foreground color according to the currently set background Color of the Button.

Now, this works when changing the color in the overridden OnApplyTemplate function, but I haven't found out how to do this dynamically (after the control is loaded).

If I could add a DependencyPropertyChanged event handler to a Controls Background property this would solve my problems, but I don't see how.

Other, rather ugly solution which would work:

- Separate backgroundworker for each Button checking the current Background color (could be a real performance killer if enough buttons are present)
- Use a custom BackgroundColor property instead of Background (would work, but does not seem very elegant)

Has anybody got a solution?

EDIT:

Ok, after seeing that the Background property of a control may change in accordance with its parents Background property (if not specifically set) I will add a separate BackgroundColor property which really only affects the background of the Button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly do this with binding converters.

http://tech.pro/tutorial/806/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters

Or, maybe easier to implement, triggers.

http://wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html

**Edit (some examples):**

Binding Converter Sample - on a UserControl only, but should show how it could be done.

in UCButton.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Test3
{
    public partial class UCButton : UserControl
    {
        public UCButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(Brush), typeof(Brush))]
    public class BrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
               object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Brush background = (Brush)value;

            if (background == Brushes.Pink)
                return Brushes.Red;
            else if (background == Brushes.LightBlue)
                return Brushes.DarkBlue;
            else if (background == Brushes.LightGreen)
                return Brushes.DarkGreen;
            else
                return Brushes.Black;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
               object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

UCButton.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test3.UCButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test3" mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="29" d:DesignWidth="82">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:BrushConverter x:Key="brushConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Name="button1" Background="{Binding Background}" Foreground="{Binding Background, Converter={StaticResource brushConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Example for using Triggers:

in MainWindow.xaml add:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="buttonBrushStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Background" Value="Pink">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Background" Value="LightBlue">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Style="{StaticResource buttonBrushStyle}" Content="Button"
   Height="23" Width="75" Background="Pink" />
<Button Style="{StaticResource buttonBrushStyle}" Content="Button"
   Height="23" Width="75" Background="LightBlue" />
```

Comment: I think I see a way no: if I put a Trigger on the Background property and check for values null or Transparent, then I can do exactly what I wanted. Thanks very much, its not the right answer but gets a +1 anyways.

Comment: Jep, but it doesn't work like that, as I now know the Background property is taken from the parent if no value is set (at least my tests lead me to believe this). So, if I put a Trigger on to the Background property (which with a converter changes the button style), then the trigger is also triggered when the parent changes its background... not my desired effect... I'm now going to go with separate BackgroundColor property... which only affects the background color of the button... but again, thank, as by going down the wrong route I found out the (for me) correct route...

Comment: In hindsight, I'll mark this as answer, as it does answer the question, as the question didn't mention the case when no Background is set on the button...

Comment: Cheers :) On that note: I would cut the binding to the background value of the parent and chain the desired effect into the triggers as well, i.e. check for null in the button background value and if it is null just bind to the parents background in that trigger. Else you might get conflicting behaviour, just as you described. As I dont know your full source I cant tell for sure whether thats the best way to go tho. And you kinda mentioned that you already solved your problem. Edit: just saw your edit - that'll work fine of course.

Comment: Or really use the `IValueConverter` as it returns a default foreground brush (black in the example) if none of the input background brushes match. So if no background brush is set it should also return a black brush instead of automatically setting to the same brush as the parent control.